# How to remove English language from Odoo v14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have an odoo server with a website and other modules installed. I have two languages, English and Spanish, and I was trying to make make English Inactive. But I get an error "Cannot deactivate a language that is currently used on a website."
I have change the Language to Spanish for all Users. including odoo boot and other inactive and internal users, And still it shows an error "Cannot deactivate a language that is currently used on a website.". How can I remove English and let only Spanish as a language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message clearly says "Cannot deactivate a language that is currently used on a website." So language is set on a website record.

Go to Website menu > Configuration > Websites   (Websites menu visible once you turn on developer mode)

[image]

Verify all website records and change default language to Spanish.

If everything is good in the website record then Go to Settings > Website and remove English language.

[image]

Comment: I followed your indications. But now it shows  "Cannot deactivate a language that is currently used by contacts" (I am Paraphrasing from the Spanish "No se puede desactivar un idioma que están usando los contactos."). I checked and the "Contacts" app is not installed. And all coontacts related to the users have the language "Spanish"

Comment: It means posted answer resolved what you asked in the questions. Now this is another issue. Check if there are any achieved Users? Also check if there are any Customer/Vendor/Company active and deactivate records!

Comment: You also need to remove English language from your Users preferences.
It's possible to edit them inside Settings -> Users -> Preferences
In case you've got many users, a good idea is to write a migration script, via odoo shell or SQL

Comment: I had to enter the database, to the table res_partner and change manually the  language of a couple partners to Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Odoo has overloaded the [write function](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/website/models/res_lang.py#L13-L17) of the `res.lang` model to avoid disabling a language that is in the list of languages (`language_ids`) of a web site:

```
if self.env['website'].search([('language_ids', 'in', self._ids)]):
    raise UserError(_("Cannot deactivate a language that is currently used on a website."))
```

For users and partners, Odoo will check if the [lang](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_lang.py#L279-L283) field is set to the language you want to disable and generate an error:

```
if vals.get('active') == False:
    if self.env['res.users'].search_count([('lang', 'in', lang_codes)]):
        raise UserError(_("Cannot deactivate a language that is currently used by users."))
    if self.env['res.partner'].search_count([('lang', 'in', lang_codes)]):
        raise UserError(_("Cannot deactivate a language that is currently used by contacts."))
```

In order to disable a language, you must update the language of users and contacts , update the websites language list and the default website language